How to hide option "Fill", "Clear", "Copy Down" from Interactive grid menu
I have followed this link to hide most of the options from the interactive grid.
Remove Oracle Apex Interactive Grid row actions
but I am not able to hide "Fill", "Clear" and "Copy Down".
I am using the commands as below :
actions.remove("selection-fill"); 
actions.remove("selection-clear"); 
actions.remove("selection-copy-down");

I am on APEX version, 24.1.5.
Is there any other way to hide these options in this version?
Regards,
Abha

Those options are evaluated when the selection changes. That post you are referring to will only fire on page load. So as soon as the selection changes, the actions will re-appear. The solution is to use a dynamic action. Example on an IG with static id emp. Only the attributes that need change are listed below, leave everything else default.
Dynamic Action:

Event: Selection Change[Interactive Grid]
Region: your interactive grid region

Action:

Action: Execute Javascript Code
Code:

var actions = apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions");
    actions.remove("selection-fill"); 
    actions.remove("selection-clear"); 
    actions.remove("selection-copy-down");

